# How do you change button text dynamically when button is subview of a custom cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, custom-cell

I am making an iOS app and it has a `Table View` with prototype cells. I configure the cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method and that works fine, but where I come into trouble is when I want to change the text in the button after it was created. I want it so that it changes the button text when I tap the button. I tried to do:

```
[button setTitle:@"Change" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

inside of the clickMethod that runs when I click the the button, but it changes the text in the last cell no matter which button I press. What I tried above doesn't work because I have multiple instances of the same button.(one in every row) So does anybody know how I can change the text of the button I click on only. Code that creates the button:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//configure cell
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
[button setTag:6789];//set tag so we can identify the button
button.Frame=CGRectMake(218, 5, 99, 53);
[cell addSubview:button];//put the button in the cell
[cell setIndentationWidth:45];
[cell setIndentationLevel:1];
return cell;//return the cell object
```

Help is greatly appreciated. I can post more code, however I don't believe that will be relevant to the question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Please Please search it on Google before asking. There are many solutions already available.

Comment: I looked before and I couldn't find anything, but I will look again.

Comment: And your cell doesn't seem custom ... is it ?

Comment: @TheTiger Yes, it is a custom cell.

Comment: `-(void)clickMethod:(id)sender{[sender setTitle:@"Change" forState:UIControlStateNormal];}` do like this.

Comment: +1 if I could for the quick and correct response. All the other places I looked talked about tagging or indexing. This is definitely the simplest solution.

Comment: I give you a chance :) You can

Comment: @TheTiger Not enough rep points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set title on button as `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method calls multiple times. If button is globally declared it will change title for last button. Just do like that

```
-(void)clickMethod:(id)sender
{
    [sender setTitle:@"Change" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

sender will have the instance of clicked button.